# Is it possible to use Intersect on complex arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have two arrays of student names and test scores.

Each array contains only distinct students (no duplicates) and is structured such that `arrStudentGroup1[0][0] = "Bob"` and `arrStudentGroup1[0][1] = "98"`.

Given two arrays is it possible to use `Intersect` to create a third array of students that exists in both `arrStudentGroup1` and `arrStudentGroup2`?

I'd like the third array to have their names and test scores. How do I do this?

Comment: Is the intersection name or name & test score?

Comment: I want to intersect the student names, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want *just* the names students that are in both groups and **not** the associated test scores, just intersect on the name array element:

```
var students1 = arrStudentGroup1.Select(group => group[0]);
var students2 = arrStudentGroup2.Select(group => group[0]);

var studentsInBoth = students1.Intersect(students2);
```

<strike>If you also want the associated test scores you'll need to implement an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) that compares the first element of each array.</strike>

If you want the associated test scores then join the two arrays:

```
var intersection = from s1 in arrStudentGroup1
      join s2 in arrStudentGroup2 on s1[0] equals s2[0]
      select new {Name = s1[0], Score1 = s1[1], Score2 = s2[1]}

foreach (var item in intersection)
{
    Console.Writeline("{0}: s1={1}, s2={2}", Name, Score1, Score2);
}
```

Comment: D Stanley, thank you.  I understand and like your both of your solutions.  I just learned that for any student on either list the test scores are ALWAYS the same on BOTH lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do somthing like this,

```
var studentsInGroup1 = arrStudentGroup1.Select(s => new 
                { 
                    Name = s[0],
                    Score = s[1]
                });

var studentsInGroup2 = arrStudentGroup2.Select(s => new 
                { 
                    Name = s[0],
                    Score = s[1]
                });

var studentsInBothGroups = studentsInGroup1.Join(
        studentsInGroup2,
        s => s.Name,
        s => s.Name,
        (one, two) => new 
             { 
                 Name = one.Name, 
                 Scores = new[] { one.Score, two.Score }
             });
```

Which should give you a handy anonymous type you can access like this.

```
foreach(var student in studentsInBothGroups)
{
   var Name = student.Name;
   var Group1Score = student.Scores[0];
   var Group2Score = student.Scores[1];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `SelectMany` there? On a `string[][]` then `SelectMany` will call a `Func<string, TResult>` on each string. You want `Select` to call a `Func<string[], TResult>` on each `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

First zip (in the general sense, rather than the `Zip` method) the arrays into a structure that groups students with scores:

Given:

```
string[][] arrStudentGroup1 = new string[][]{new string[]{"Bob","98"}, new string[]{"Alice","98"}, new string[]{"Charles","78"}, new string[]{"Dariah","99"}};
string[][] arrStudentGroup2 = new string[][]{new string[]{"Bob","98"}, new string[]{"Fiona","98"}, new string[]{"Eve","78"}, new string[]{"Dariah","99"}};
```

Then:

```
var zipped1 = arrStudentGroup1.Select(student => new {Name = student[0], Score = student[1]});
var zipped2 = arrStudentGroup2.Select(student => new {Name = student[0], Score = student[1]});
```

Now get the intersection. Note that if the same student name was in one but with a different score, it would **not** count as an intersection. That can be dealt with too, but I'm interpreting your question as not wanting that case. Let me know if I read you wrong:

```
var inter = zipped1.Intersect(zipped2);
```

Now, you can ideally work with this anyway, or even with `new {Name = student[0], Score = int.Parse(student[1])}` above and have a number instead of a string (more useful in most cases), which frankly is nicer than dealing with an array of arrays, along with being more typesafe. Still, if you really want it in the same format string[] format:

```
var interArray = inter.Select(st => new string[]{st.Name, st.Score});
```

And if you really, really want the whole thing in the same string[][] format:

```
var interArrays = interArray.ToArray();
```

Or for the one-line wonder (less good readability mostly, but sometimes it's nice to put a query on one line if there's other things going on in the same method):

```
var interArrays = arrStudentGroup1
  .Select(student => new {Name = student[0], Score = student[1]})
  .Intersect(
    arrStudentGroup2
    .Select(student => new {Name = student[0], Score = student[1]})
  ).Select(st => new string[]{st.Name, st.Score}).ToArray()
```

Output:

```
{"Bob", "98"},{"Dariah", "99"}
```

Edit: Alternatively, define an `IEqualityComparer<string[]>` like:

```
public class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
  public bool Equals(string[] x, string[] y)
  {
    if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    if(x == null || y == null)
      return false;
    return x.SequenceEqual(y);
  }
  public int GetHashCode(string[] arr)
  {
    return arr == null ? 0 : arr.Select(s => s == null ? 0 : s.GetHashCode()).Aggregate((x, y) => x ^ y);
  }
}
```

Then just use it directly:

```
var intersection = arrStudentGroup1.Intersect(arrStudentGroup2, new StudentComparer());
```

Gives the same output. Simpler really, but my instincts upon seeing arrays being used as objects was to get it into a real object as soon as I can, and really, it's not a bad instinct - it can make much else easier too.